# MissingpluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocementsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guys this program consists of two pages named student list and studentdetail it don't make any error in the analyzer but in emulator when I open the first page that display list of students and tap on any student and go to the student detail and wanting  to delete , update or goback to the fist page it says MissingpluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocementsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
where is the error
is the error in this code in the studentlist page

```
  void navigateToStudent(Student student, String appTitle) async {
bool result =
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
  return StudentDetail(student, appTitle);
}));

if (result) {
  updateListView();
}
```

}
or the error in this code in studentdetail page

```
  void goback() {
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

}
there is the entire project in this link
https://github.com/abdelrahman992-cpu/studentfinal

Answer (score 0):

stop the debugging proses and start again don't just hot reload it won't work, because some package need to rerun the app don't forget to flutter clean too if it still not working

Comment: I did this stopped the debugging and started again but the error appears again!